# pythonで任意の要素数の組からなるリストを作りたい

Tags: python, python3

pythonで以下のようなリストを作成したいと考えています。

```
[[i, 3+j] for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]
#[[0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5]]
[[i, 3+j, 6+k] for i in range(3) for j in range(3) for k in range(3)]
#[[0, 3, 6], [0, 3, 7], [0, 3, 8], [0, 4, 6], [0, 4, 7], [0, 4, 8], [0, 5, 6], 
#[0, 5, 7], [0, 5, 8], [1, 3, 6], [1, 3, 7], [1, 3, 8], [1, 4, 6], [1, 4, 7], 
#[1, 4, 8], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 7], [1, 5, 8], [2, 3, 6], [2, 3, 7], [2, 3, 8], 
#[2, 4, 6], [2, 4, 7], [2, 4, 8], [2, 5, 6], [2, 5, 7], [2, 5, 8]]
```

要素数4なら[[i, 3+j, 6+k, 9+l] for i in range(3) for j in range(3) for k in range(3) for l in range(3)],...というようにしたいのですが、要素数を後から決めたいのです。
要素数を引数にして任意の要素数からなるリストを作成する方法などありますでしょうか。
解決の糸口をいただければと思います。

また、今後同様の問題にあたった場合、どのような検索をすればよいか教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のような感じでよいと思います。
指定の要素数に見合った各要素の値の候補を用意して、それらをitertoolsのproductで全組み合わせ列挙します。

```
from itertools import product

N = 2
a = [list(map(lambda v: v+i*3, range(3))) for i in range(N)]
print(a) # [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]

ret = [p for p in product(*a)]
print(ret) # [(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
```

> また、今後同様の問題にあたった場合、どのような検索をすればよいか教えていただけると助かります。

まずは結果の生成ルール（仕様）を推測して決めます。
そのさい、今回の問題では順列、組合せについての知識が必要かと思いました。
あとはルールどおりの動作をするコードを書きます。
コードを書いたあとで、それを簡単に実現できるパッケージがないか検索してもよいでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

NumPy での場合 (すべて NumPyというわけではないが)

```py
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

N = 3
p = np.split(np.arange(3 *N), N)
list(product(*p))
#[(0, 3, 6),
# (0, 3, 7),
# (0, 3, 8),
# (0, 4, 6),
# (0, 4, 7),
# (0, 4, 8),
# 以下続く
```

---

`itertools.product` 相当も NumPyで行う場合

```py
import numpy as np

def fn(num):
    return np.stack(np.meshgrid(
        *np.split(np.arange(3 *num), num)), -1).reshape(-1, num)

fn(3)

# array([[0, 3, 6],
#        [0, 3, 7],
#        [0, 3, 8],
#        [1, 3, 6],
#        [1, 3, 7],
#        [1, 3, 8],
#        [2, 3, 6],
#(略)
```

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208118/using-numpy-to-build-an-array-of-all-combinations-of-two-arrays

Answer (score 0):

[More Itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) の [chunked](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.chunked) を使う場合。

```py
from itertools import product
from more_itertools import chunked
from pprint import pprint

def cartesian_product(n):
    return [*product(*chunked(range(3*n), 3))]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in (2, 3):
        print(f'n = {i}')
        pprint(cartesian_product(i), compact=True)

# n = 2
# [(0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]
# n = 3
# [(0, 3, 6), (0, 3, 7), (0, 3, 8), (0, 4, 6), (0, 4, 7), (0, 4, 8), (0, 5, 6),
#  (0, 5, 7), (0, 5, 8), (1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 7), (1, 3, 8), (1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 7),
#  (1, 4, 8), (1, 5, 6), (1, 5, 7), (1, 5, 8), (2, 3, 6), (2, 3, 7), (2, 3, 8),
#  (2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 7), (2, 4, 8), (2, 5, 6), (2, 5, 7), (2, 5, 8)]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product
`itertools.product`のrepeat引数がまさにそのための機能だと思います。

```py
from itertools import product

for x in product(range(3), repeat=4):
    print(x)
```

でまず様子を見ると

```
(0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1)
(0, 0, 1, 2)
(0, 0, 2, 0)
(0, 0, 2, 1)
(0, 0, 2, 2)
(0, 1, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0, 2)
(0, 1, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1, 1)
以下略
```

と出てくるので、2や3も試して、欲しいものだなと判断します。

i, j, k, l,,, → i, 3+j, 6+k, 9+l,,, は割と素直に内包表記で書けて、

```py
N = 4
[[i * 3 + n for i, n in enumerate(x)] for x in product(range(3), repeat=N)]
```

とできます。
i, 3+j, 6+k, 9+l,,, が 0×3+i, 1×3+j, 2×3+k, 3×3+l,,, に見えるかどうかは数学の能力かなと思いました。

---

検索で届く範囲ではないと感じました。
私は「これはitertoolsに必要なものがあるだろう」という直感しました。
Pythonの標準ライブラリの範囲は一通り目を通しておくのがいいのではないでしょうか。